# How to tell if two TypeReferences refer to the same type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, mono.cecil

With System.Reflection, I can compare two `Type` objects with `==`.

How can I determine whether two `TypeReference` objects refer to the same static type in Mono.Cecil? I'd like an approach that works for generic types, generic type definitions, arrays, pointers, generic parameters, primitives, etc. and not just for a subset of types.

Comment: It was a known (unresolved) problem: https://goo.gl/5WRw2H and https://www.mail-archive.com/mono-cecil@googlegroups.com/msg01472.html and https://goo.gl/ZPZySn